# how to use google safe browsing api to check if an URL is safe to visit in android application

Tags: android, android-layout

want to call Google Safe Browsing api in application on Default Browser andriod.The app needs to use the google safe browsing api to check if an URL is safe to visit. If not it needs to display a message give the user the option to reject (or load) the page. Safe Browsing Lookup API should be easiest to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Very broad question, do you have any code written?

Here are some [Examples](http://code.google.com/apis/safebrowsing/lookup_guide.html) for using the Safe Browsing Lookup API.

Basically you will need to issue a request with the questionable domain name, and based upon the response determine if it is ok or not. If it is not, then use `AlertDialogBuilder` or some other method to notify the user and have Continue and Exit buttons.

Comment: how to use in android application when browser launch and user go to any website first check that url is valid then show dailog to continue anyway or exit.please describe in detail.

Comment: Check the URL first from your activity, then based upon the user's response to the warning (assuming it is shown), either launch the browser intent or do not.

Comment: Please Give me a example.i am beginner plz.plz give me a demo i will be very thankful to u

Comment: take a look at the examples I linked and post what you have so far, and I can help you fill in the gaps

Comment: my application will run in background how i check the browser goes to which site?in my application background services...

Comment: quite a bit different..sounds like you need to write a browser plugin

Comment: i want to make a application like lookout...plz help that check browser automatically browser going to which site?